# Recording Fender Stratocaster with KA 6 Audio Interface and Ableton Live

Tags: electric-guitar, homerecording

I've been producing beats for a while but am only just beginning to record live instruments and include them in my work. I have a Fender Stratocaster that I believe is from the 80s, and a Komplete Audio 6 audio interface. I'm also working with Ableton Live as a DAW. I've been able to record through the audio interface on an acoustic guitar that has an electrical pickup installed, but no input signal is being detected when I try to connect the Fender strat to the audio interface with a 1/4 inch jack. I am certain the cord itself works, since I've been able to use it with the other guitar. Does anybody have any suggestions for troubleshooting this, or do I need to run the guitar through a pre-amp beforehand? I can't figure out what I'm missing and the manual for the audio interface says that I should be able to just plug the guitar directly into KA6 with a 1/4inch jack. Many thanks for any help you can give!!

Comment: If your strat has a pickup selector switch and two tone pots and a volume pot make sure you try it all 3 or maybe 5 positions of the switch with all three knobs fully open. Not sure which way is fully open try all 3 fully turned one way in all 3 selections and then the other way.

Comment: @b3ko thank you! Trying out different positions with all three knobs fully open allowed me to finally get an input signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem with your Fender Stratocaster - most likely a loose or disconnected wire on the inside. Your best bet is to take the guitar to a local music shop for repair.